# OpenSSL not picking up CAs in certs folder by default

Tags: openssl, certificates, tls

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I am getting error for certificate validation error if the CApath is not explicitly set

Tried several solution. But nothing works. It is causing so much of issue to install new packages on my system (tried at least on two system)

Successful command:

```
openssl s_client -connect secure.ogone.com:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ 

Success with Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Unsuccessful command

```
openssl s_client -connect secure.ogone.com:443 -showcerts 

Failed with Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I tried following solution  based on the wiki responses but it is also not working

```
openssl x509 -noout -hash -in /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem 2c543cd1    
openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash_old -in /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem 7999be0d    
openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash -in /etc/ssl/certs/GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem 2c543cd1
```

I can see the difference in hash values

I tried adding a script to create symbolic link with `-subject_hash_old` and `-subject_hash`.

But the problem continues to happen and I get the error code `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`.

```
#!/bin/sh
Create following script to create symbolic links in /etc/ssl/certs
Link with subject_hash_old and subject_hash is successfully created


for FILE in /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem
do
   hasholdsub=`openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash_old -in $FILE`
   hashsub=`openssl x509 -noout -subject_hash -in $FILE`

   echo $hasholdsub $hashsub

   ln -s $FILE  $hasholdsub.0
   ln -s $FILE  $hashsub.0
   cat  $FILE >> ca-certificats-gen.crt
done
```

But this problem is still existing

Please help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please try using `-CAfile` instead of `-CApath` and point to the single concatenated CA certificates file. E.g.:

```
openssl s_client -connect secure.ogone.com:443 -showcerts \
                 -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

This works for me, showing `verify return:1` and a full certificate chain.

Background information: This `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is managed by the `update-ca-certificates` command, simply concatenating all system-wide installed certificates, including those manually installed in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`.